# Adding new columns to trac AccountManager plugin

Tags: plugins, edit, trac

I want to add new columns to the trac `AccountManager` plugin, I already edited the admin_user.html, but in python what do I have to edit, which files. I want to add two more data field. ex: group and telephone, How can I do that?

**UPDATED**

This is the two field I added in the admin_user.html

```
<div class="field">
          <label>Telephone:<br />
            <input type="text" name="tel" class="textwidget"
                   value="${account.tel}" /></label>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
          <label>Group:<br />
            <input type="text" name="group" class="textwidget"
                   value="${account.group}" /></label>
        </div>
```

and I also added the two column to the table:

```
<td>${acct.group}</td>
<td>${acct.last_visit}</td>
```

But I'm not familiar with python, so I don't know how can I add the functionality in the python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check UserManagerPlugin for it's ability to add arbitrary new columns?

But maybe you want it some additions to the generic view in *users* admin page, right? These must be optional, if you care for universal use, of course.

In 'admin.py' you'll see a Class 'AccountManagerAdminPages' with a module '_do_users'. This module is primary handler for all requests related to the admin page in question. While the beginning is about processing 'POST' (user input) everything after the line 'if listing_enabled:' will prepare the page displayed next. You'll see various sources, but main source is query to Trac db table 'session_attribute'.

Again I'd like you to take a look at UserManagerPlugin - all what you may want and more.

Disclosure: I'm the current maintainer of AccountManagerPlugin.

Comment: Thanks, I've commented your answer. But with few Python experience you'll have a hard time to manage all this: db backend, read/write/change actions, ... Really think about taking this task to the appropriate mailing-list <th-users@lists.trac-hacks.org>, try to work with the maintainer of the UserManagerPlugin and with me, if you have further issues and in case the maintainer of UserManager is not active anymore (dunno right now).

Comment: I modified the source, so now it's working. Thanks for your help. In the web_ui.py _create_user function have to edit in this function as well.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. So I moved essential parts of my previous comment to your question into this answer. The rest: Obviously false assumptions about the chance that you could manage this task. Not worth to be read anymore - deleted. Please consider to accept my answer in its current form, to show that it has been helpful.